# Pagination link problem when reaching the second page

Tags: pagination

I've an issue with the pagination function in WordPress.

Although the anchor text is correct, when I hit the URL for some reasons WP changes it from

`www.site.com/page?page=2` to `www.site.com/page/2` thus generating a 404 error.

My pagination call is like the following:

```
 $paginate_links = paginate_links( array(
                    'base' => preg_replace('/\?.*/', '/', get_pagenum_link()) . '%_%',
                    'prev_text' => __('«'),
                    'next_text' => __('»'),
                    'mid_size'  => 5,
                    'current'   => $current,
                    'total'     => $totalpages
                ));
```

The strange thing is that using the same function in an archive page I get this working properly.
Any idea on what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have the pretty urls turned on?

What happens if you add the format parameter to paginate_links?

```
'format'       => '?page=%#%',
```

Full reference here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links